# Store SVN credential globally in Jenkins

Tags: svn, jenkins

In my Jenkins, I have 20 jobs(all have SCM as **SVN**).

**XYZ** user has only read right to all these svn repos.
Can I save username and password of **XYZ** user in Jenkins globally in a such way that I dont need to put his username and password in all 20 jobs ? Because it will easy for maintainance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store credentials with [Credentials Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Credentials+Plugin). One of it's consumers is a [Subversion Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Subversion+Plugin):

[image]

You can manage your credentials at Manage Jenkins -> Manage Credentials.

Be sure, that you have Subversion Plugin with 2.5.1 or higher version, because of issue [#29211](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-29211).

Comment: Actually I had Credential plugin but of older version. Upgrading it solved the problem. Thanks.